# google apps script loop through range argument

Tags: javascript, for-loop, google-apps-script, google-sheets, custom-function

I'm trying out google apps script editor and a simple for loop gives me weird results.

Say I have a spreadsheet

[image]

in script editor i write a function:

```
function calculate(array) {
 var result = 0;

 for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  result += array[i]; 
 }

  return result;
}
```

I would expect a returned value to be 9 but instead I get 045
returning array.length I get 2 as expected
returning array[0] I get 4 as expected

I tried googling it but i found some weird workarounds using array.map function.
Am I doing something wrong, is it not supposed to be plain javascript?

Answer (score 1):

Got it. I had to convert values to number: `result += Number(array[i]);`

Comment: im surprised that works. the actual issue is that array is an array of arrays, not an array of numbers.